# Grails search hasMany property using Criteria

Tags: grails, groovy, criteria

```
class Order {
    static hasMany = [deliveries:Delivery]
}

class Delivery {
    Order order
    DeliveryDate date
}
```

I want to search all Orders that have DeliveryDate within date1 and date2.
I'm a beginner at using criteria in Grails. How should I do it?

Thanks!

EDITED:
My current code:

```
  return Order.createCriteria().list(params, {
        if(params.fromDate) {
            deliveries {
                gt("deliveryDate", params.fromDate)
            }

        }
        if(params.toDate) {
            deliveries {
                lt("deliveryDate", params.toDate)
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: Rather than writing the code for you, why don't you show us what you have tried and what didn't work about what you have tried? Did you read the documentation on criteria? http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm still currently working on it while waiting for any help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HQL in Grails like this:

```
    def query =
    """
    select x.order from Delivery x
    where x.date >= :date1 and where x.date1 >= :date2  
    """
    def result = Delivery.executeQuery(query, [date1: date1, date2: date2])
```

This should give your result.